# Prisma - Como tratar arquivos ponto e vírgula "csv"?

Tags: prisma

O título da pergunta refere-se a csv porque é amplamente usado e tem a mesma lógica mas o meu servidor produz a seguinte saída:

```
 ifname  |        username        |    calling-sid    |       ip        | type  | comp | state  |   uptime   
---------+------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+------+--------+------------
 ppp10   | anamariade             | 00:1A:3F:74:03:93 | 10.10.10.3      | pppoe |      | active | 7.02:26:48 
 ppp365  | fabianepinow           | 98:DE:D0:FF:AE:C1 | 10.10.10.112    | pppoe |      | active | 6.19:21:57 
 ppp621  | nilsonbrito            | 78:44:76:8D:57:07 | 10.10.10.77     | pppoe |      | active | 6.19:21:31 
 ppp405  | andreparente           | DC:9F:DB:EE:CA:24 | 10.10.10.232    | pppoe |      | active | 6.16:54:32
```

Quero que cada linha `pppX` seja um índice da tabela e dentro da tabela suas respectivas colunas: `tab[0].username` `tab[0].ip`, eu já li o manual mas do jeito que fiz os índices não casam:

```
local tabfinal = {}                           // declara uma nova tabela
local saida = es.abra("saida.txt","leitura")  // abrindo o arquivo
    local texto = saida:leia("*t")            // lê todo conteúdo
    local tabtemp = texto:analise("|")        // quebraria o texto em vários índices
    para i,v em pares(tabtemp) inicio         // laço para preencher a tabela final
        se nao v:procure("|") entao           // testa o separador
        tabela.insira(tabfinal,1,v)           // alimenta a tabela
        fim
    fim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu criei uma função que processa a string tal qual está na sua pergunta, não fiz a leitura de arquivo, coloquei a string direto, mas basta adaptar de acordo com sua necessidade:

(Obs.: os duplos colchetes são usados para strings multilinha)

Para quem tiver interesse link do manual:

http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz/blog/manual-basico/

```
 local s = [[
     ifname  |        username        |    calling-sid    |       ip        | type  | comp | state  |   uptime   
    ---------+------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+------+--------+------------
     ppp10   | anamariade             | 00:1A:3F:74:03:93 | 10.10.10.3      | pppoe |      | active | 7.02:26:48 
     ppp365  | fabianepinow           | 98:DE:D0:FF:AE:C1 | 10.10.10.112    | pppoe |      | active | 6.19:21:57 
     ppp621  | nilsonbrito            | 78:44:76:8D:57:07 | 10.10.10.77     | pppoe |      | active | 6.19:21:31 
     ppp405  | andreparente           | DC:9F:DB:EE:CA:24 | 10.10.10.232    | pppoe |      | active | 6.16:54:32 
    ]]

    funcao tab_remova(tab,c) //tabela sempre é passada por referência
      local removaitem = tabela.remova;
      local str_apare = string.apare;
      para i=1,#tab inicio
        se tab[i] == c entao 
          removaitem(tab,i); //remove este indice da tabela e recompoe a tabela.
        fim     
      fim
      para i=1,#tab inicio
        tab[i]=str_apare(tab[i]); //apara os espaços ao redor das strings;
      fim
    fim

    funcao obt_tab(s)
      local lin, col,tab,tmp=nulo,nulo,{},nulo;
      lin = s:analise('\n');
      se nao lin entao retorne nulo, 'erro ao analisar string'; fim
      col = lin[1]:analise('|'); //guardamos os nomes da colunas aqui 
      tab_remova(col,'|');//remove todos os '|';
      tab_remova(lin,'\n');//remove todos os '\n' em lin
      tabela.remova(lin,2);//remove o -----------+----------- ...
      //agora o indice 3 é realocado para o 2, o 4 para o 3 e cada indice um abaixo.
      para i=2,#lin inicio //um valor para cada item em col;
        tmp = lin[i]:analise('|');
        tab_remova(tmp,'|');//remove os '|';
        tab[#tab+1] = {};// tab[i] = {campo1=valor,campo2 = valor2 ...}
        para j=1,#col inicio
          tab[#tab][col[j]] = tmp[j];//tab[i] [nomeCol] = tmp[j]
          //imprima(tmp[j]);
        fim
      fim
      retorne tab;
    fim 



    /* -------------------- TESTANDO ---------------- */


    local tab = obt_tab(s);

    //teste percorrendo toda a tabela:
    para i = 1, #tab inicio
      poe'\n-----------------------\n';
      //cada indice é uma nova tabela (recorde);
      para k,val em pares(tab[i]) inicio  // a função iteradora pares() percorre a tabela devolvendo chave/valor.
        imprima(k,'=',val);
      fim
    fim

    //teste usando indice manual [1]:
    poe'\n-------------- *** -------------\n';
    imprima(tab[1].username, tab[1].ip);
    poe'\n-------------- FIM -------------\n';
```

Comment: Seu código ficou bem trabalhado! Aqui eu consegui fazendo apenas um cadeia:analise("|") e preenchi a tabela a partir do segundo índice.